# Codeigniter Sum contents of the records in a field

Tags: codeigniter, sum

I am trying fetching some information from mysql database and I am displaying it using the following script(I am using Codeigniter).

database order_details

```
order_id | qty  | price
4          2      0.9
4          1      0.9
4          1      0.85
```

in my view i have

```html
<?php 
 $sum = $sum[0]->price;
 $qty = $qty[0]->qty;
 $total = $sum * $qty;

?>

<div class="container">

 <div class="well">

 <a href="<?php echo base_url('billing/view')?>" class="btn btn-success"><</a>
 <?php foreach($customer as $data):?>
 <a href="<?php echo base_url('print_pdf/reciept_pdf/'.$data->oid)?>" class="btn btn-info">PDF</a>
 <a href="<?php echo base_url('print_pdf/download_pdf/'.$data->oid)?>" class="btn btn-warning">Download PDF</a>

 
  
   <table class="table table-bordered">
   <br>
   <tr>
    <td>Nome cliente:</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->customer_name;?></td>
    <td>NIF:</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->customer_contact;?></td>
    
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Pagamento:</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->payment;?></td>
    <td>Data da Ordem:</td>
    <td><?php echo $data->date;?></td>
   </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>


   <tr>
    <td>Unid.</td>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>Qtd.</td>
    <td>Valor</td>
   </tr>
   <?php 
   foreach($results as $data):?>
   <tr> 
    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo $data->product_name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data->qty;?></td>
    <td>€ <?php 
     
    echo number_format($data->qty * $data->price,2);?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>

    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Total da Venda (IVA Incl)</td>
    <td>€ <?php echo number_format($total ,2) ;?></td>
    
   

    
    
   </tr>

   <tr>
    
    <td>Valor do IVA</td>
    <td>€ <?php echo number_format($vat = 0 * $total ,2) ;?></td>
    <td>Valor iliquido</td>
    <td>€ <?php echo number_format($vatable =$total - $vat ,2);?></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Tabela IVA</td>
    <td>€ <?php echo number_format($vatable =$total - $vat ,2);?></td>
    <td>Valor iliquido</td>
    <td>€ <?php echo number_format($vatable =$total - $vat ,2);?></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>VAT-Exempt</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Less:SC/PWD Discount</td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>VAT Zero Rated</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Amount Due</td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>

     <tr>
    <td>VAT - 0%</td>
    <td>€ <?php echo number_format($vat = 0 * $total,2) ;?></td>
    <td>Adicionar: IVA</td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Total Amout Due</td>
    <td>€ <?php echo number_format($total,2)?></td>
   </tr>

   </table>
   
 </div>

</div>
```

but the result is 10.60 and not 3.55

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GWx6.jpg)

in models i have this

```
public function get_sum($oid)
{

    $this->db->select_sum('price')
             ->where('order_id',$oid);
    $query = $this->db->get('order_details');

    return $query->result();
}

public function get_qty($oid)
{

    $this->db->select_sum('qty')
             ->where('order_id',$oid);
    $query = $this->db->get('order_details');

    return $query->result();
```

in controllers i have this:

```
public function view_id($oid)
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){

        $data['qty'] = $this->billings->get_qty($oid);
        $data['sum'] = $this->billings->get_sum($oid);
        $data['results'] = $this->billings->fetch_order_details($oid);
        $data['customer'] = $this->billings->fetch_customer_details($oid);
        $this->load->view('order/order_details',$data);

        }else{
            redirect(base_url(''));
        }   
    }
```

Any help for this issue?

Comment: is this price 0,9 ??

Comment: 0.9 ... yes it is the price field! many thanks

Comment: Where is you calculation on the code ?? Show complete view code

Comment: Describe what do you want to calculate - what algorithm should be 3.55?

Comment: 3.55 = (2*0.9)+(1*0.9)+(1*0.85)

Comment: i  edit the post with the complete view code, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

ok, is solved by now:

how?

insert in models a new sintax,

```html
public function get_qty($oid)
 {
  
  $this->db->select('sum(price * qty) as qty', FAlSE)
     ->where('order_id',$oid);
  $query = $this->db->get('order_details');

  return $query->result();
 }
```

in the view i change  $sum = $sum[0]->price; to $sum = 1;

thanks for all comunity